# Erros ao inserir imagens em mysql

Tags: php, mysql, imagem, banco-de-dados

Olá, gostaria de inserir imagens no banco de dados para um projeto pessoal.
A imagem é enviada ao banco sim, mas não sem mostrar 3 erros, segue o código e os erros :

```
<?php
$servidor = 'localhost';
$banco    = 'banco_tcc';
$usuario  = 'root';
$senha    = '';
$link     = mysql_connect($servidor, $usuario, $senha);
$db       = mysql_select_db($banco,$link);

if (isset( $_POST['Enviar'])) {

    $foto = $_FILES["foto"];

    if (!empty($foto["name"])) {

        $largura = 2000;
        $altura = 2000;
        $tamanho = 99999999999999999999999999;

        if(preg_match ("/image(jpeg|png)$/", $foto["type"])) { 
           $error[1] = "Isso não é uma imagem.";
        } 

        $dimensoes = getimagesize($foto["tmp_name"]);

        if($dimensoes[0] > $largura) {
            $error[2] = "A largura da imagem não deve ultrapassar ".$largura." pixels";
        }

        if($dimensoes[1] > $altura) {
            $error[3] = "Altura da imagem não deve ultrapassar ".$altura." pixels";
        }

        if($foto["size"] > $tamanho) {
            $error[4] = "A imagem deve ter no máximo ".$tamanho." bytes";
        }

        if (count($error) == 0) {

            preg_match("/.(gif|bmp|png|jpg|jpeg){1}$/i", $foto["name"], $ext);

            $nome_imagem = md5(uniqid(time())) . "." . $ext[1];

            $caminho_imagem = "tmp_name/" . $nome_imagem;

            move_uploaded_file($foto["Fotos"], $caminho_imagem);

            $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO ManterGaleria VALUES ('','".$nome_imagem."')");

        }

 if (count($error) != 0) {
            foreach ($error as $erro) {
                echo $erro . " ";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> Undefined variable:Error in line 52
>
> Undefined index:Fotos in line 60
>
> Undefined variable:Error in line 66

Como poderia consertá-los sem modificar o código completamente?

Comment: Quais são as linhhas citadas no erro?

Comment: `if (count($error) == 0) {`

`move_uploaded_file($foto["Fotos"], $caminho_imagem);`

`echo $erro . ";`

Comment: Leitura recomendada: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/579/por-que-n%C3%A3o-devemos-usar-fun%C3%A7%C3%B5es-do-tipo-mysql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Undefined variable:Error in line 52
>
> Undefined variable:Error in line 66

Aqui diz que a variável `$error` não foi iniciada. Inicie o `array` da variável perto dos parametros da sua conexão sql, logo acima do primeiro `if`:

```
$servidor = 'localhost';
$banco    = 'banco_tcc';
$usuario  = 'root';
$senha    = '';
$link     = mysql_connect($servidor, $usuario, $senha);
$db       = mysql_select_db($banco,$link);

$error    =  Array();
```

> Undefined index:Fotos in line 60

Este erro diz que o indice `$foto['Fotos']` não foi definido, verifique se no seu html qual o nome correto do indice do form de upload e altere na linha informada.

Comment: Eu não sei da onde vem esse código da pergunta, um código de upload com variável `$error` sempre tem erro de escopo. `$error` so vai existir de cair em algum if do contrario ela não vai existir e só será checada `if (count($error)` LOL. +1